# Python stock screener won't stop running

Tags: python, finance, stock

New coder and first time posting a question. I would really appreciate some help on a stock screener that I am trying to run. Basically I pull a bunch of stock tickers (around 7000) from a CSV file and then scrape data for each of the stocks from Finviz (financial data website). Then I have some criteria that I put it through based on an investment book. The code probably looks terrible, so I am very open to feedback if you have the chance to take a look at it.

Problem is, I still haven't gotten it to work. I don't mean that it stops and there is an error, I mean it just keeps running forever. There must be some part of my code that is making it take so long. Any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Stock ticker URLs
# Local path
stock_tickers = r'local path/stock_symbols.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(stock_tickers)

stocks = df['Symbol'].tolist()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests


def get_fundemental_data(df):
    for symbol in df.index:
        try:
            url = ('http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=' + symbol.lower())
            soup = bs(requests.get(url).content, features="lxml")
            for m in df.columns:
                df.loc[symbol, m] = fundemental_metric(soup, m)
        except Exception as e:
            print(symbol, 'not found')
    return df


def fundemental_metric(soup, metric):
    return soup.find(text=metric).find_next(class_='snapshot-td2').text


metric = ['P/B',
          'P/E',
          'Market Cap',
          'Current Ratio',
          'Forward P/E',
          'PEG',
          'Debt/Eq',
          'EPS (ttm)',
          'Dividend %',
          'ROE',
          'ROI',
          'EPS Q/Q',
          'Insider Own'
          ]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=stocks, columns=metric)
df = get_fundemental_data(df)

# CLEAN UP THE DATA

# Replace '-' and '' values with NaN
df = df.replace('-', np.NaN)
df = df.replace('', np.NaN)

# Some metrics have 'B' or 'M' at the end to indicate billions or millions of $
# Convert all those values to floats measured in billions of $
df.loc[df['Market Cap'].str.strip().str[-1] == 'M', 'Market Cap'] = df['Market Cap'].str.strip().str[:-1].astype(float)\
                                                                   / 1000
df.loc[df['Market Cap'].str.strip().str[-1] == 'B', 'Market Cap'] = df['Market Cap'].str.strip().str[:-1].astype(float)

# Remove "%" signs
df['ROI'] = (df['ROI'].str[:-1])
df['ROE'] = (df['ROE'].str[:-1])
df['Dividend %'] = (df['Dividend %'].str[:-1])
df['EPS Q/Q'] = (df['EPS Q/Q'].str[:-1])
df['Insider Own'] = (df['Insider Own'].str[:-1])
df['Inst Own'] = (df['Inst Own'].str[:-1])

# Convert all values to floats
df = df.astype(float)

# Create a new DF for easy manipulation
df_II = df

# INTELLIGENT INVESTOR CRITERIA #

# Businesses which are "adequately sized" (i.e. market cap of >$2 billion)
df_II = df_II[(df_II['Market Cap'] > 2)]

# Businesses with a 'strong financial condition' (i.e. current ratio > 3:2)
df_II = df_II[(df_II['Current Ratio'] >= 1.5)]

# Price of stock no more than 1.5 times net asset value. Price-to-book ratio is less than 1.5
df_II = df_II[(df_II['P/B'] <= 1.5)]

# Business has demonstrated earning power (i.e. EPS Q/Q > 10%)
df_II = df_II[(df_II['EPS Q/Q'] > 10)]

# Business earns good returns on equity while employing little or no debt (i.e. Debt/Equity < 1 & ROE > 10%)
df_II = df_II[(df['Debt/Eq'] < 1) & (df_II['ROE'] > 10)]

# Management having substantial ownership in the business (i.e. Insider ownership > 15%)
df_II = df_II[(df_II['Insider Own'] > 15)]

xl_filepath = r'local file path/BG_StockPicks.xlsx'
df_II.to_excel(xl_filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: To gather some more information you could add some logging (some print statements will work for now) to see where your program gets to. You could also run it in debug mode and add breakpoints throughout to see which calls are taking the most time

Comment: Also you might want to have a read about making copies of data frames, specifically around passing by reference in python. I’m not sure the code df_II = df is behaving exactly as you expect

Comment: We expect *narrow*, *specific* questions. At least figure out where your code is hanging, and then build the shortest possible program that hangs the same way (cutting out everything not strictly needed to reproduce the exact problem when run without changes). See the [mre] definition in the Help Center, and "Tips for Trimming" at http://sscce.org/

Comment: You might want to see if there is a way to get *all* stock information in a single downloadable file and then process that. Making 7000 independent requests is unlikely to perform as well, or be looked on very kindly by the service provider :-)

Comment: You have to provide the layout of stock_symbols.csv. Just from a finance perspective, you might want to cluster the stocks into sectors first and then set sector specific criterias.